# Parent RecyclerView not updating from Child Activity Change with coroutine support cancelled

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview, kotlinx.coroutines

I have a situation where if I do not cancel my coroutine in my parent activity (that displays a recycler) view it may potentially cause a crash once I start my child activity.   The coroutine opens a SQL database and gets the data for the recyclerview.   I implement it as follows:

```
protected val coroutineMarkerSup = SupervisorJob()
protected val myMarkerSQLScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + coroutineMarkerSup)

fun doSomething() {
myMarkerSQLScope.launch {
    val user = withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
        doSomehingInTheBackGround()//gets the SQL database
    }
    //Any code here is blocked till doSomethingInTheBackGround is finished
    finalTaskOnceCoroutineFinished()
}
}

fun finalTaskOnceCoroutineFinished() {

//recyclerView.adapter = adapter
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()//refresh recyclerview
}

    @CallSuper
    override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    coroutineMarkerSup.cancel()
}
```

Then once I have made a change in the child activity that will affect the parent activity I restart the coroutine in the parent activity as follows.

```
override fun onRestart() {
super.onRestart()
coroutineMarkerSup.start()
doSomething()
}
```

If I go back one more activity to the parent of the parent and forward again, the recycler view displays the updated content.

So, to get around the issue I commented out the coroutineMarkerSup.cancel() line in onPause()  and it works fine, but then I am concerned about the app crashing.

So is it ok to not cancel the coroutineMarkerSup or is there a proper way to do this that I have overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

So I need to cancel any background tasks but not close down the coroutine supervisor itself.

To do that I found the cancelChildren() call as follows:

```
@CallSuper
override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    coroutineMarkerSup.cancelChildren()
}
```

From my reading **.cancelChildren()** shuts down any background threads but keeps the supervisor active.   Hope this makes sense and helps someone.
Here is a [link](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlin.coroutines.-coroutine-context/index.html) to more info on the cancel children method.